# Graphical representation of the current value into the total value

Tags: android

Suppose I have a total value of 2000, while my current value is 180. I would like to present it graphically as follows:

[image]

How could I do that? I was looking for many charts, but I did not find such a solution anywhere. 
Is there any open source that provides such graphical representation of values?

Comment: Please add the code to your question that'd you've written so far to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TableLayout to achieve this.
Your layout will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
   android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TableLayout>
```

Then in your code you could populate your table like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         int  totalValue = 2000;
         int currentValue = 180;
        int rowsNumber = 10;
        int columnsNumber = 10;

        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsNumber ; i++) {

            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourRowDrawable);

            for (int j = 0; j < columnsNumber; j++) {
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

                imageView.setImageResource(this.getCellDrawableId(i,j,totalValue ,currentValue ));

                tableRow.addView(imageView, j);
            }

            tableLayout.addView(tableRow, i);
        }
    }
}

private int getCellDrawableId(int i, int j,int totalValue ,int currentValue ){
      if(/*some logic here*/)
           return R.drawable.greenCell;
       return R.drawable.emptyGrayCell;
}
```

**P.S.**: Where R.drawable.greenCell, R.drawable.emptyGrayCell, R.drawable.yourRowDrawable are appropriate drawable to represent your grid.

Also I did not test this code, only writeen it here like snippet, so some errors may be present here